# jQuery .find() with an iD

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JS:**

```
this.par = $(this).find("p");
```

**HTML:**

```
<p></p>
```

The problem is that I dont want to find `p` tag, but rather a `div` with a specific ID like this one below.

```
<div id="abc"></div>
```

Comment: Surely it would have been quicker and easier for you to read the jQuery API, than to type that out and then wait for an answer?

Comment: I was using # for id but it seemed there is other error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do that. Don't add properties to the html elements. This is better:

```
var par = $(this).find('#idOfElement')
```

Storing the result in `this.par` is a very bad idea, since `this` refers to a DomElement.

---

What you might be looking for is jQuery `.data()`:

```
$(this).data('par', $(this).find('#idOfElement'))
```

Which allows you to associate `#idOfElement` with `this`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
var myDivObj = $("#abc");
```

Take a look at the list of [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

**Additional Information:**

It's difficult to tell by your code what you're trying to do, but based on what you've posted, there is no reason to use `$(this)`. The ID selector alone should meet your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can just use the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector):

```
$(this).find('#abc');
```

Since ids should be unique on the page, you may as well just use it as the constructor:

```
$('#abc');
```

If this *isn't* exactly the same, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.par = $(this).find("#abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

use id selector

```
this.par = $(this).find("#abc");
```

but id is uniqe you can remove $(this).find and use this code

```
this.par = $("#abc");
```